# Can we append message of Gmail to Yahoo using Java Mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

We want to write a program using Java Mail-1.5 that can append the message of Gmail to Yahoo account. **Is this possible with Java Mail API?**  What we are trying is that we have downloaded eml of Gmail message at our system, now we want to append these messages to one Yahoo account. On trying this we are getting this errors -

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: A4 NO [SERVERBUG] LIST Server error - Please try again later;
   nested exception is: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A4 NO [SERVERBUG] LIST Server error - Please try again later
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:351)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.doList(IMAPProtocol.java:1100)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.list(IMAPProtocol.java:1046)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder$1.doCommand(IMAPFolder.java:518)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doProtocolCommand(IMAPFolder.java:2991)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doCommand(IMAPFolder.java:2931)
    ... 8 more
```

Sometime this process producing similar errors as some are below listed -

```
A33 NO Invalid "flag-list" : Contains unsupported flag or other invalid item.
A18 BAD [CLIENTBUG] APPEND Command arguments invalid
A19 BAD [CLIENTBUG] APPEND Command arguments invalid
A21 NO [SERVERBUG] LIST Server error - Please try again later
A12 BAD [CLIENTBUG] APPEND Command arguments invalid
.............
............
```

Is this possible to append message of Gmail (eml) to Yahoo account using Java Mail API??

Thanks,

Neelam Sharma

Comment: May be posting related code helps. INVALID flag-list, but we are not sure what values you set there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a question about what the Yahoo mail server supports.  As you've discovered, the Yahoo mail server sometimes fails operations due to a "server bug".  It may take a few retries to get the operation to work.

The APPEND failure seems to be due to the server limiting what flags you can set when you append the message.  The debug output will show you what flags it's trying to set.  You might need to clear those flags in the message before appending the message.

See the [JavaMail populate.java demo program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples), and in particular the dontPreserveFlags option in that program.

Comment: Thanks, my problem get resolved by clearing flags from message before appending - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158152/how-to-remove-user-flags-from-message

Comment: By removing flag list from message solve my issue of appending message at other account but now sometime I am catching error - 1. "A319 BAD [CLIENTBUG] Additional arguments found after last expected argument" 2. "A172 NO [SERVERBUG] EXPUNGE Server error - Please try again later", how can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: The IMAP APPEND command allows an optional set of flags and an optional date.  It sounds like Yahoo Mail may be unhappy with the date, although it's hard to tell without seeing the actual protocol exchange.  JavaMail gets the date from Message.getReceivedDate() and if that's null from Message.getSentDate().  If both return null, no date is sent.  You can create your own MimeMessage subclass that always returns null for these, then use the copy constructor to copy the message to your new subclass.

Comment: For - ""A319 BAD [CLIENTBUG] Additional arguments found after last expected argument" -- I debugged the message it have atleast one date "Message.getSentDate()" but "Message.getReceivedDate()" is null. This error not always occur, sometime I get appended message at destination side. HOW CAN I GET IT SOLVED?? This is protocol trace for one message - 
http://neelam.sharma.s3.amazonaws.com/a_protocol/protocoltrace.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1383157764&Signature=8TnzNBbwFcdv1sX57I8fDFzvy5A%3D

Comment: If you're always sending the date, and it's only failing sometimes with this error message, you'll need to ask Yahoo why it only fails sometimes.  Other than the workaround of never sending the date, as I described above, I don't have any better ideas for you.