# How to remove user Flags from message?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I am appending IMAP message of Gmail account to Yahoo account using JavaMail-1.5. My requirement is to remove user flag from message, because they are producing error while appending message to other folder. I want to remove all user flags from message?

Below is the code for getting flags.

```
  Flags flags = message.getFlags();
  Flag[] systemFlag = flags.getSystemFlags();
  String[] userFlag = flags.getUserFlags();
```

Please suggest how to remove `userFlag` from my message.

Thanks

Comment: what is FLAG here ?? are you dealing with mails ???

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid yes I am dealing with emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is get resolved by this code -

```
 MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage((MimeMessage) message);
 Flags flags = mimeMessage.getFlags();
 mimeMessage.setFlags(flags, false);
```

This code remove the flags that are causing fail to the appending message of Gmail to Yahoo.

Comment: i was about to post you the same , but the best scenario is , users find it out their selves +2 for effort