# How to fetch messages from specific label(folder) using IMAP in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

When I `list` folders I don't have 'snoozed' folder there.
I Googled and it seems like 'snoozed' is sort of internal label that is not available through IMAP (is it correct??). So I want to find where 'snoozed' mails are really kept.

1. Can I do it using fetch command for instance? How?

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good explanation that this is something that it's not possible in this [thread.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87643/how-to-access-snoozed-messages-via-imap-in-gmail)

Pretty much the [Snooze](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7622010) feature is implemented internally within Gmail UI and so Imap clients won't be able to replicate this behavior, therefore you won't be able to find emails snoozed when using a mail client.

Comment: But where are 'snoozed' messages really kept? As far as I understood, I can't access 'snoozed' folder, but what about messages?

Comment: The messages are in the allmail folder. You can try to snooze a message, then find it in allmail and try `x uid fetch 1234 (flags x-gm-labels)`, maybe the currently deployed code publishes either a flag or a label. (Your next question is perhaps [how to find the allmail folder,](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6154) whose name depends on language.)

Comment: [Arnt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/857727/arnt) is right, emails snoozed are in the allmail folder, the way that a snoozed email is managed within Gmail UI is not managed by adding the email to a different folder as these are special labels as: `label:pinned`, `label:trips`, etc. You can query them through API as noted in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828695/android-java-mail-gmail-mark-as-unread-inbox-snooze)